# Tk Filedialog giving back a tuple

Tags: python, tkinter, copy

I am trying to take a file and put it into all directories 1 level down.

```
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not tuple
```

```
import shutil
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose file/s')
path = filedialog.askdirectory()

for dirs in path:
    shutil.copy(files, dirs)
```

I thought that this would be simple, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ```askopenfilenames``` returns a ```tuple```?

Comment: I would assume that that's what is happening based on the error that it's returning...

Comment: I may not have explained well enough... the "files" is the selection of files that I want to copy. The path is the "path" that contains the folders that I want to copy the files into. I want to iterate over all of the folders in the "path" and put the files into those folder.

Comment: You cannot use `files` in `shutil.copy()`.  You need to loop through items in `files` like `for file in files: shutil.copy(file, path)`.  Also `path` is string, so you cannot use for loop on it.

Comment: So, if I want to a number of files into all of the subdirectories of a folder, I need to loop through the files, but I can't loop through a list of paths because it's a string? What if I convert to somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is "`askopenfilenames`", it returns the results in the form of a tuple. You can iterate over it and move the files to the directory selected:

```
import shutil
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose file/s')
j=filedialog.askdirectory()
path = [os.path.join(j,i) for i in os.listdir(j) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(j,i))]

for fols,dirs in zip(path,files):
    shutil.copy(dirs, fols)
```

Comment: I may not have explained well enough... the "files" is the selection of files that I want to copy. The path is the "path" that contains the folders that I want to copy the files into. I want to iterate over all of the folders in the "path" and put the files into those folder.

Comment: @AdrianCharlesBlood check the updated answer

Comment: I love the solution, but now kicks out a PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "/file.pdf'. Is this because it's trying to iterate over the file while using the file?

Comment: @AdrianCharlesBlood Check the updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate everything you've done, and I've spent the last 5 minutes trying to fix the final part of it myself, but... it only copies into the first folder in the list, and then stops rather than iterating through all of them.

Comment: @AdrianCharlesBlood, I cannot reproduce the error. It copies all of it

Comment: The issue I'm having is, I select all files from the files dialog. Then I select the to directory from the j dialog. If there are 5 folders in the j dialog parent directory, it's only copying the files into the first subdirectory, where I need to to copy into all 5 folders (which it's not iterating through yet) I've tested in multiple locations.

Comment: As an addendum, When I have 3 files, it will put file 1 into folder 1, file 2 into folder 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for your guidance and input.
The final answer, in order to select files and copy into all subdirectories inside of a folder, the answer that worked is below.

```
import shutil
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose file/s')
j=filedialog.askdirectory()
path = [os.path.join(j,i) for i in os.listdir(j) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(j,i))]

for paths in path:
    for file in files:
        shutil.copy(file, paths)
```